# Installing a whl from a url while using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

In my setup.py I have a number of libraries specified in the `required_libraries` argument. These are typically of the form: `oauthlib==2.0.6`. Now I also want to install a library using a wheel hosted at a remote url: `http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi-zero/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/output-artifacts/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp27-none-any.whl`. Simply adding this as an entry in the list of `required_libraries` results in an error:

`'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement,....`

The documentation on setuptools isnt much help. Does anyone have experience doing these kinds of installs? I'd imagine this would be a common issue but I'm probably googling the wrong words

Answer (score 5):

Use `dependency_links` argument; this is described in [`setuptools` docs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi). Example:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    install_requires=['tensorflow'],
    dependency_links=[
        'http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi-zero/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/output-artifacts/tensorflow-1.7.0-cp27-none-any.whl',
    ],
)
```

Running the setup script:

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
...
Processing dependencies for spam==0.0.0
Searching for tensorflow
Downloading http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi-zero/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/output-artifacts/tensorflow-1.7.0-cp27-none-any.whl
Best match: tensorflow 1.7.0
Processing tensorflow-1.7.0-cp27-none-any.whl
Installing tensorflow-1.7.0-cp27-none-any.whl to /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow-py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages
writing requirements to /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow-py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow-1.7.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt
Adding tensorflow 1.7.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installing toco_from_protos script to /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow-py27/bin
Installing saved_model_cli script to /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow-py27/bin
Installing freeze_graph script to /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow-py27/bin
Installing toco script to /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow-py27/bin
Installing tensorboard script to /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow-py27/bin

Installed /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow-py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow-1.7.0-py2.7.egg
...
```

Comment: Great. Is there a way to specify to use a different dependency link depending on how the project is built? eg, if i do `pip install -e [foo]` use url `www.foo.com/wheel.whl` and if i do `pip install -e [bar]` use `www.bar.com/wheel.whl` or some such?

Comment: You mean when you are using [extras](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)? The extras argument is processed by the package managers (`pip`/`easy_install`) and is not passed into the setup script at all.

Comment: yes, i have been using extras to specify additional dependencies that I need in different situations. Is it possible to add a whl referenced by a url as above as an extra dep?